# How to Widget Test a BoxDecoration in Flutter

Tags: flutter, testing, widget, containers, widget-test-flutter

I want to test the color change of a BoxDecoration but I don't know how to get the color...

Here is the code

```
testWidgets('CustomCheckbox Test', (WidgetTester tester) async{
    await tester.pumpWidget(Sizer(
        builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
          return MaterialApp(
            home: Material(
              child: CustomCheckbox(
                iconColor: Colors.purple,
                activeColor: Colors.yellow,
              )
            ),
          );
        }
    ));

    expect(find.byIcon(Icons.check_outlined),findsOneWidget);

    await tester.tap(find.byType(Container));
    await tester.pump(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    final container = tester.widget<Container>(find.byType(Container));
    print(container.decoration);
  });
```

When I print `container.decoration`, I get `BoxDecoration(color: Color(0x00000000), border: Border.all(BorderSide(Color(0x66c8c8c8), 1.8, BorderStyle.solid)), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.8))`. I want to get the color, even if it is transparent like here, but I don't know how to access to it...

container.decoration.color does not work, here is the error:

[image]

Thanks for your help !

Chris

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration/color.html

Comment: container.decoration.color does not work...

Comment: does not work? it returns `null` or something?

Comment: I just put the photo of the error at the end of the post :). The issue is that it's a type of Decoration and not BoxDecoration

Comment: simply cast it to BoxDecoration class

Comment: Oh yeah simple of that, thanks !

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can test the `BoxDecoration` properties

```
print((container.decoration as BoxDecoration).color);
```